# StreamPlot is giving correct answer while VectorPlot gives wrong answer

Tags: plotting, vector

I'm trying to plot this vector <1,3*y^(2/3)> using vector plot. but it gives me a wrong answer.

```
VectorPlot[{1, 3*y^(2/3)}, {x, -8, 3}, {y, -3, 4}, Axes -> True, 
AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

But if I try [`StreamPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StreamPlot.html) it gives me the correct answer.

[image]

```
StreamPlot[{1, 3*y^(2/3)}, {x, -8, 3}, {y, -3, 4}, Axes -> True, 
AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

What am I doing wrong in [`VectorPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/VectorPlot.html)?

Comment: Didn't understand what you mean.
Can you explain a little bit more?
Thank you.

Comment: deleted comment, because streamplot says `StreamPlot does not show streamlines at any positions for which the v_i etc. do not evaluate to real numbers.` but when I looked at `VectorPlot` it also said the same thing. So I do not know why VectorPlot shows vectors in negative `y` but not `StreamPlot`. May be `VectorPlot` is the one which should not show that region. If you type `Table[3*y^(2/3), {y, -3, 4, .1}]` you see that in negative region y becomes non-real.

Comment: To see this, try `StreamPlot[Evaluate[{1, Re[3*y^(2/3)]}], {x, -8, 3}, {y, -3, 4}, 
 Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic]` and now you get similar plot to `VectorPlot`

Comment: I got your point. But how can I Solve it now?

Comment: `how can I Solve it now` other than what I showed above, which is to use `Re`, I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

If you want reals, then try plots as

```
VectorPlot[{1, 3*CubeRoot[y^2]}, {x, -8, 3}, {y, -3, 4}, Axes -> True,
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

and

```
StreamPlot[{1, 3*CubeRoot[y^2]}, {x, -8, 3}, {y, -3, 4}, Axes -> True,
  AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

They then match.

Comment: Thank you all. Problem solved